# Array Argument not Extensible in Tag Function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, tagged-templates, ecmascript-2018

Typically, arrays in javascript are extensible, but this is not true for the array passed as the first argument of a tag function:

```js
let ary = [1,2,3];
console.log(Object.isExtensible(ary));
// returns true

function tag(ary, ...expressionResults)
{
    console.log(Array.isArray(ary));
    //returns true
    console.log(Object.isExtensible(ary));
    // returns false
}
tag`test`;
```

Where, exactly, in the specification, is this array deemed non-extensible? I'm not even sure if I'm looking at the right [spot](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-gettemplateobject).

Comment: Not sure what the variables in that section of the spec are referring to exactly, but `SetIntegrityLevel(someVar, "frozen").` really sounds like it freezes the object, which will make it non-extensible (steps 12 and 14)

Comment: I don't like this array not being extensible. See why [here](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/1375).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were looking in the right spot. The linked spec even offers a note as to why (emp. mine):

> **NOTE 2** Each *TemplateLiteral* in the program code of a [realm](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#realm) is associated with a unique template object that is used in the evaluation of tagged Templates ([12.2.9.6](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-template-literals-runtime-semantics-evaluation)). **The template objects are frozen** and the same template object is used each time a specific tagged Template is evaluated.

If you want to understand the actual execution, first look at the tagged templates' runtime semantics are specified in [Section 12.3.7.1](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-tagged-templates):

> #### 12.3.7.1 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation
>
> *MemberExpression: MemberExpression TemplateLiteral*
>
> […]
>
> 5. Return ? [EvaluateCall](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-evaluatecall)(*tagFunc*, *tagRef*, *TemplateLiteral*, *tailCall*).

If you take a look at abstract operation [EvaluateCall](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-evaluatecall):

> #### 12.3.4.2 Runtime Semantics: EvaluateCall (*func*, *ref*, *arguments*, *tailPosition*)
>
> […]
>
> 3. Let *argList* be [ArgumentListEvaluation](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-template-literals-runtime-semantics-argumentlistevaluation) of *arguments*.

So, when calling a tag function with a template literal, the ArgumentListEvaluation of the TemplateLiteral is passed as the argument to the tag function. Taking a look at [ArgumentListEvaluation](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-template-literals-runtime-semantics-argumentlistevaluation):

> #### 12.2.9.3 Runtime Semantics: ArgumentListEvaluation
>
> *TemplateLiteral: NoSubstitutionTemplate*
>
> […]
>
> 2. Let *siteObj* be [GetTemplateObject](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-gettemplateobject)(*templateLiteral*).

Looking at operation [GetTemplateObject](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-gettemplateobject), we see the culprit:

> #### 12.2.9.4 Runtime Semantics: GetTemplateObject (*templateLiteral*)
>
> […]
>
> 14. Perform [SetIntegrityLevel](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-setintegritylevel)(*template*, "frozen").

Where *template* is array passed to the tag function. We see that it's explicitly frozen. If you want to go a level deeper, see [SetIntegrityLevel](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-setintegritylevel):

> #### 7.3.14 SetIntegrityLevel (*O*, *level*)
>
> The abstract operation SetIntegrityLevel is used to fix the set of own properties of an object. This abstract operation performs the following steps:
>
> […]
>
> 3. Let *status* be ? *O*.[[PreventExtensions]]().

And taking a look at [[[PreventExtensions]]](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-isextensible-o) of an ordinary object, we see that operation [OrdinaryPreventExtensions](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ordinarypreventextensions) is called:

> #### 9.1.4.1 OrdinaryPreventExtensions (*O*)
>
> When the abstract operation OrdinaryPreventExtensions is called with Object O, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Set *O*.[[Extensible]] to **false**.
> 2. Return **true**.

So the [[Extensible]] internal slot is explicitly set to false.

Comment: I wish I had your comprehension skills with specification. Your elaboration was very helpful to me.